# Phonegap Android 'Application Error' when no network present. How to avoid?

Tags: android, networking, cordova, detection

I'm using Phonegap Android and it's building well and very happy so far. My app incorporates some web pages. If I'm on a network everything is fine but if there is no network, I get a dialog box that states "Application Error, the URL could not be found. (http://myurl.com). This doesn't happen on the iPhone implementation of phonegap. Is there a way to turn off this alert or change the alert to "No Network Detected" or something less detailed that doesn't list the URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in network.isReachable function ;)

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_network_network.md.html#Network

Comment: Yes, I've implemented that script and it works when the page loads. However if the data connection is lost after the page loads, the error with the page name comes up again. Seems like that script checks on page load but alert appear if it can't find a page on the web. Would just like to turn this alert off.

Comment: IC.. perhaps you should try calling that function each time you trigger a web page and then add your custom error message or simply put.. do not launch the web page at all in order to avoid the msg.